# How to inverse a view's visibility with bit manipulation

Tags: java, android, bit-manipulation

I want to inverse the visibility of a view on a SurfaceView upon user click. A click makes the view visible on screen. The next click makes it invisible, and so on.
I already tried `view.setVisibility(Integer.reverse())` and `view.setVisibility(View.GONE ^ view.getVisibility())`, but none of them work. The latter does not even compile.

Comment: `Flag not allowed here`

Comment: @MikeM. it is actually a syntax error as I type the code.

Comment: You wouldn't use bit manipulation to do this, as visibility is a trinary state and not a bitfield.  If you just wish to switch gone to visible, the standard way is view.setVisibility(view.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);  However if you want ot include the possibility of invisible you'd need to be clearer on what you want.

Comment: Why do you need to use bit manipulation for this?

Comment: I was seeking a concise way to do that via unary or binary operators. Seems, though, this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view's visibility is not binary, as in there are not just two states. Views can be in three states: VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE. Which two are you trying to switch between?

Normally you set a view's visibility with something like:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This is actually equivalent to:

```
view.setVisibility(8);
```

becuase the three values are each public static ints in the View class. They are:

```
public static final int VISIBLE = 0x00000000;
public static final int INVISIBLE = 0x00000004;
public static final int GONE = 0x00000008;
```

They are each power's of 2, so in binary their values would be:

```
VISIBLE =   ...0000;
INVISIBLE = ...0100;
GONE =      ...1000;
```

So Integer.reverse() isn't really what you want. VISIBLE is always 0, and to go from INVISIBLE to GONE you need to shift left.

Answer (score 0):

XOR binary operation will be applicable in case of the current set state was the same integer value or zero (VISIBLE).
I've written a simple test to demonstrate how the toggle logic would be implemented.

```
    @Test
    fun toggleVisibility() {
        // toggle GONE
        var visibility = VISIBLE
        visibility = visibility xor GONE
        assertEquals(visibility, GONE)

        visibility = visibility xor GONE
        assertEquals(visibility, VISIBLE)

        // toggle INVISIBLE
        visibility = VISIBLE
        visibility = visibility xor INVISIBLE
        assertEquals(visibility, INVISIBLE)

        visibility = visibility xor INVISIBLE
        assertEquals(visibility, VISIBLE)
    }
```